# prevent object prototype functions to be sent along with object attributes by ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototype

I have defined the following "class" in js, plus some basic functions (the code is simplified):

```
function Word(name, description, solved) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.solved = category;
}

Word.prototype.getPoints = function(){
    return parseInt(this.solved);
};
```

I intended to pass along a concrete instance of Word to the server using an AJAX request containing only the **attributes** of the Word-instance, but I discovered that the **entire object**, along with its functions, is sent as well, as var_dump shows:

```
array(4) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "to protrude"
  ["description"]=>
  string(29) " to stick out from a surface"
  ["solved"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["getPoints"]=>
  string(3) "NaN"
}
```

On the server side then, the word-object is converted into a string that is written into a document, where I really don't need those functions. 
I only want to send the object attributes, i.e. name, description, solved, but NOT the additional functions I have defined. 
I wondered if there's an easier way to do this than cropping each instance manually, be it on client or server side. I don't like that "solution", as I'd have to arrange the cropping algorithm with each of those trivia functions.

I'd be more than happy if you could point me into the right direction. I have used the search function extensively but I couldn't find anything or I was unable to find the right words to frame my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the way you are serializing the object, so if you want help we that, you have to post the corresponding code. And, are you really using Prototype.js or did you tag the question as such by mistake?

Comment: Do you also have a mistake: ` this.solved = category;`

Comment: So what is the issue? `var x = new Word("a","b","c"); console.log(JSON.stringify(x));`

Comment: @epascarello, of course. missed the obvious solution. works fine. didn't know stringify was used for just that. the "mistake" is a typo.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, marking the questions as prototype.js was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672258/prevent-object-prototype-functions-to-be-sent-along-with-object-attributes-by-aj#comment40119845_25672258) helpfully pointed out, [`JSON.strigify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will automatically remove functions.

You could use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to strip out the functions and then convert the string back to an object using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var noFun = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( lotsOfFun ) );
```